# Edit image, using openGL

Tags: ios4, opengl-es, uiimagepickercontroller, opengl-es-2.0

I have been doing some searching the last couple of days and I have been curious how to do this. I have a UIImagePickerController.

So I want to add a effect like black and white, sepia, etc. I am creating a custom UIImagePickerVController and I am curious. Can this be done with OpenGL ES? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible through the use of pixel shaders using OpenGL-ES 2.0. You could also write an Objective-c++ routine that gets all the pixels of your image into an array then applies a custom algorithm to modify the color of the image.

#### Edit:

Here are some links that might help get you started.

http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/76816-image-processing-tutorial/

http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/ImageProcessing/Algorithms.htm

Comment: Would it be able to display in a live stream and not be slow? You know what I mean? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Code / Links would be great too! I can't seem to find anywhere that will help me... Thanks again.